# Impossible to run test with TestCaseData generated from RhinoMocks stub

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I am working with **C#** in **Visual Studio 2015 Community**, with **NUnit3** and **Rhino Mocks** and attempting to write a test for a component of my system (it is NOT a unit test).

I have encountered a problem when trying to use a generated stub as the argument to a `TestCaseData` that is provided to a `TestCaseSource`. I get the following errors in the output window:

```
Test adapter sent back a result for an unknown test case. Ignoring result for 'MyTest(Castle.Proxies.IMyInterfaceProxy4c6c716794ef48818f41fd5012345ead)'.
Test adapter sent back a result for an unknown test case. Ignoring result for 'MyTest(Castle.Proxies.IMyInterfaceProxy4c6c716794ef48818f41fd5012345ead)'.
```

The test name appears in the VS2015 integrated test-runner when I rebuild the test project, but as soon I try to run it it becomes greyed out.

Here there is some sample code based on my test code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Rhino.Mocks;
using System.Collections;

namespace FenixLib.Core.Tests
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        int Property { get; }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    class TestMocks
    {
        [Test, TestCaseSource( "TestCases" )]
        public void MyTest(IMyInterface what)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

        public static IEnumerable TestCases()
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData ( CreateFake ( 2 ) );
            yield return new TestCaseData ( CreateFake ( 4 ) );
        }

        public static IMyInterface CreateFake ( int something )
        {
            var fake = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyInterface> ();
            fake.Stub ( x => x.Property ).Return ( something );

            return fake;
        }
    }
}
```

I have been able to overcome the problem if I create a decorator class that wraps the generated stub:

```
public class Decorator : IMyInterface
{
    IMyInterface decorated;

    public Decorator ( IMyInterface decorated )
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public int Property
    {
        get
        {
            return decorated.Property;
        }
    }
}
```

And change the prior `return fake;` by `return new Decorator ( fake );`. Everything works fine then.

However this is a bit of a pain in my real scenario because my interface does not only have a single property as in this example but is more complex (and yes I know that VS2015 can generate the code for implementing through the decorated field, but that's not the point). Besides, it feels pointless to use RinhoMocks if I am going to end up creating an implementation of the interface I am wishing to not fully implement for my test purposes.

Anyway, what annoys me is that I do not understand why it does not work and therefore I ask:

**Can anyone help me to understand why the code without the decorator did not work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At discovery time, TestExplorer creates a process and asks our adapter to find tests. Your TestCaseSource method runs and generates the cases. It has a name generated by Moq.

Much later in the lifetime of the program, your test is executed by Visual studio, which creates a **different** process and asks the adapter to run the tests. Since we are running in a new process, the adapter has to discover (that is generate) the cases all over. Most likely, Moq generates them with a different name. The originally created cases are never run and NUnit runs these new cases, which, from the point of view of TestExplorer, were never discovered in the first place.

I haven't seen this symptom before, but we have a similar problem with random arguments being regenerated at execution time. It's essentially a problem with the architecture and could only be resolved if the Adapter could somehow keep the originally loaded test assembly around to be found by the execution process.

Comment: Ok then I guess the decortating class should be the way to go if I want this to work (there is still some benefit using RinhoMocks as I have to create different stubs and I will only need one decorator class).

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer as no-one else seems to be adding anything to the discussion.

Comment: Not surprising. The issue of volatile test names under the adapter is a pretty obscure one. :-)